# Firing event handler while refreshing DataGridView contents

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, datagridview, event-handling

I am making an application that refreshes on every second datagridview content. I noticed that sometimes CellClick event is not fired when I press on a cell. What is the problem and how can I deal with it?

Refresh thread method(its on separate thread):

```
private void RefreshThread()
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (true)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            UpdateDataGridWithChannels();
        });
     }
    watch.Stop();
    int elapsedMs = (int) watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    if (elapsedMs < Constants.NetworksRefreshThreadInterval)
        Thread.Sleep(Constants.NetworksRefreshThreadInterval - elapsedMs);
}
```

UpdateDataGridWithChannels method:

```
private void UpdateDataGridWithChannels()
{
    List<Channel> Chnls24 = Channels.Values.Take(14).ToList();
    DataGridViewChannels24List.UpdateChannelsView(Chnls24);
}
```

UpdateChannelsView(its in my custom datagridview):

```
public void UpdateChannelsView(List<Channel> chls)
{
    foreach (Channel Chnl in chls)
    {
        if (!BindingList.Contains(Chnl))
            BindingList.Add(Chnl);
        else
            BindingList.Update(Chnl);           
    }
    BindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true; 

    BindingList.ResetBindings(); 

    BindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = false; 
}
```

Comment: `while(true) { ...; break; }` looks very strange. Do you ever get `BindingList.Update(Chnl);` called (set breakpoint there)?

Comment: Originally there was a switch in the while(true), but in order not to obscure the code, I had put only the important part, but I forgot to remove the break, my mistake. Everything is working fine, just the event handler problem.

Comment: It's even more confusing without `break;`. Can you please try to provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? While preparing such example, you have very high chances to spot a problem yourself (happens to me many times).